# Back up Evolution mail (settings, messages and attachments)

Tags: backup, 19.04, email, evolution

I'm trying to save up some space on my Google account and to locally back up everything's that currently only stored online.
Is there an easy way to back everything up locally, including attachments?
"File->Back up Evolution Data..." takes like 2 seconds and results in a single <1MB file.

Answer (score 0):

**Evolution** uses (3) folders for storing its data/config:

```
$HOME/.cache/evolution
$HOME/.config/evolution
$HOME/.local/share/evolution
```

A simple tar command should do this trick:

```
tar cvpzf evolution_backup.tar.gz $HOME/.cache/evolution $HOME/.config/evolution $HOME/.local/share/evolution
```

You can probably skip the cache directory, as it *should* get rebuilt automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked and it seems these 3 folders combined only contain a small part of the files I'd like to back up (the cache directory being by far the largest). So I'm still trying to figure out a way to back up everything...

Comment: I use archiving and move everything older than 6 months to local folders. You'll see a huge increase in ~/.local/share/evolution once this is completed.